# Checking if the function returns null or not

Tags: javascript

I have this scenario:

```
var myResult = scope.inside.GetMyData() || scope.outside.GetMyData();
```

One of those functions will containe the method. I need to check if the first one returns anything, then if not then use the other one.

In the first case, it works just fine. But if the scope is null, then it gives me this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'scope' of null.

I might do if / else and check for null, but I would like to use || way if possible.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Trying to access that deep into a tree when a parent is null will always fail. You need to validate that each child isn't null first.

Comment: Sometimes "if" and "else" are clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `&&`:

```
var myResult = scope && (scope.inside.GetMyData() || scope.outside.GetMyData());
```

or ternary operator:

```
var myResult = !scope ? null : (scope.inside.GetMyData() || scope.outside.GetMyData());
```